# $t^3$ is never equal to

Tags: number-theory

> Let $t$ be a real number such that $t^2=at+b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. Then for any choice of positive integers $a$ and $b$, $t^3$ is never equal to:
>
> (A). $4t+3$
>
> (B). $8t+5$
>
> (C). $10t+3$
>
> (D). $6t+5$

We have $t^3 = at^2+bt$ and so for (A) we have $t^3 = 4t+3 = 4(at^2+bt)+3$. I don't see how to continue since this is a cubic equation. Is there an easier way of finding a contradiction?

Comment: hint :$$t^2=at+b\\ t^3=at^2+bt \to t^3=a(t^2)+bt\\t^3=a(at+b)+bt \\t^3=(a^2+b)t+ab$$

Answer (score 4):

You are close, but dont stop with $t^3=at^2+bt$. Since you know what $t^2$ is equal to:
$t^3=a(at+b)+bt=(a^2+b)t+ab$

Now try this for every possiblility.
F.ex. (A): $4=a^2+b$ and $ab=3$ would be possible for $a=1$ and $b=3$.

Since in the all the cases the second term is a prime number either $a$ or $b$ has to be $1$ (since they are both positiv Integers) which makes it easy to check whether it's possible or not.

Edit: more detailed this gives you a quick solution if it is possible, if it doesn't give you a quick solution we can try to get a contradiction.

With the method above we see it works for (A), (C) and (D), so we want to check out (B) .

Since obviously $t$ divides $t^3$ we use the form $t^3=8t+5$ and divide it by the $t$. Now we get that $5$ has to be dividable by $t$ (note that normally this is not necessarly true, but here it holds because $8t$ is dividable by $t$). 
Because $t$ has to be a positive integer it is now either $1$ or $5$.

Case $t=1$:
Is not possible since $1^3\neq 8+5$

Case $t=5$:
Is not possibe either since $5^3=75\neq45=8*5+5$.

Therefore we get a contradiction, (B) is not possible.

Thank you for pointing this out TonyK.

Comment: From $(a^2+b)t+ab=4t+3$, it doesn't follow that $a^2+b=4$ and $ab=3$. Your approach shows that A, C, and D are possible; but it doesn't show that B is impossible.

Comment: Why doesnt it? View it as a polynom.

Comment: $t$ is a real number, not a variable.

Comment: Equatin coefficents i would say.

Comment: Or divide both sides by t and then the rquation follows since divison with 'rest' is unique.

Comment: No, you can't do that here. The question is about real numbers, not polynomials.

Comment: Sorry meant the euclidean division.

Comment: With that the equations which you questioned should follow.

Comment: There's no requirement given that the equality (B) has to true for integer $t$. Only $a$ and $b$ are required to be integers. You need to show that under the given condition $t^3=8t+5$ has no solution at all; not having an integer solution is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

$t^2 = ax + b$

$t^3 = cx +d$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are integers.

See 2 cases:

1. $t^2=at+b$ has an integer root $\implies$ t is integer
2. $t^2=at+b$ has no integer root $\implies$ roots are $p+\sqrt{q}$ and
   $p−\sqrt{q}$, where $p$, $q$ are rational. You can see that if one
   of these roots is a root of $x^3=cx+d$, the second is the root of
   $x^3=cx+d$ too, and the third root must be an integer

$\implies$ $t^3-cx-d = 0$ has an integer root

A) $t = -1$

B) No integer root

C) $t= -3$

D) $t= -1$

So, answer is (B)

Comment: From $t^3=ct+d$, you can't deduce that $t^3-ct-d=0$ has an integer root.

Comment: @TonyK,  from $t^3= ct+d$ and $t^2 = at+b$

2Cases: 1)second equation has an integer root
2)second equation has no an integer root

Comment: I don't understand that at all.

Comment: 1. $t^2=at+b$ has an integer root  => t is integer
2. $t^2=at+b$ has no an integer root => roots are $p+\sqrt(q)$ and $p-sqrt(q)$, where p, q is rational. You can see what if one of this roots is a root of $x^3=cx+d$, the second is  the root of $x^3=cx+d$ too, and third root must be an integer

Comment: Now that makes sense! You should put all that into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$t^2=at+b\\ t^3=at^2+bt \to t^3=a(t^2)+bt\\t^3=a(at+b)+bt \\t^3=(a^2+b)t+ab$$

$$t^3=(a^2+b)t+ab=4t+3 \to ab=3 \to \\a=1 ,b=3 \to t^3=(1^2+3)t+1.3 \\$$
$$t^3=(a^2+b)t+ab=10t+3 \to ab=3 \to \\a=3 ,b=1 \to t^3=(3^2+1)t+1.3 \\$$
$$t^3=(a^2+b)t+ab=6t+5 \to ab=5 \to \\a=1 ,b=5 \to t^3=(1^2+5)t+1.5 \\$$
so answer is :"B"

Comment: From $(a^2+b)t+ab=4t+3$, it doesn't follow that $a^2+b=4$ and $ab=3$.

Comment: @TonyK Is the question asking about identically equal to each of the choices?

Comment: @user19405892: Well, it's your question! And the wording is not very clear. Is it translated from a foreign language?